# Java generic method doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a generic method for data deserialization.

My code:

```
public <T> ExportedData<T> getExportData(T classType, String exportUri) {
    Response response = _client.get(exportUri);
    // System.out.println(response.body.toString());
    ExportedData<T> exportedData = GsonSingleton.getGson().fromJson(response.body.toString(), new TypeToken<ExportedData<T>>() {
        }.getType());
    return exportedData;
}
```

The `response.body`:

```
{"totalResults":2,"limit":50000,"offset":0,"count":2,"hasMore":false,"items":[{"DevicesIDs":"","EmailAddress":"zatokar@gmail.com"},{"DevicesIDs":"","EmailAddress":"oto@increase.dk"}]}
```

The way I call the generic method:

```
ExportedData<AccengageOutboundContact> exportedData = generalBulkHelper.getExportData(new AccengageOutboundContact(), uriLimitAndOffset);
```

The `AccengageOutboundContact`:

```
public class AccengageOutboundContact {

   public String EmailAddress;
   public String DevicesIDs;

}
```

And the `ExportedData`:

```
public class ExportedData<T> {
    public int totalResults;
    public int limit;
    public int offset;
    public int count;
    public boolean hasMore;
    public List<T> items;
}
```

I would expect to get an ArrayList of `AccengageOutboundContact` objects. What I am getting is ArrayList of `StringMap`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this one a bunch of times, but there does not seem to be a good duplicate to link.

---

Basically the problem is that `T` is erased to `Object`, in your generic method. So the `TypeToken` that is created, does not hold the needed information.

This results in deserializtion to a `StringMap`.

---

You can fix this by passing a complete `TypeToken` to your method:

```
public <T> ExportedData<T> getExportData(TypeToken<ExportedData<T>> tt, String exportUri) {
    Response response = _client.get(exportUri);
    // System.out.println(response.body.toString());
    ExportedData<T> exportedData = GsonSingleton.getGson().fromJson(response.body.toString(),
        tt.getType());
    return exportedData;
}
```

Then call like:

```
generalBulkHelper.getExportData(new TypeToken<ExportedData<AccengageOutboundContact>>(){},
    uriLimitAndOffset);
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it, but why is T erased to Object?

Comment: Because [that's how Java's generics works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens).

Comment: So are you saying that T is always erased to an Object? If so, to me the generic methods are losing point, we could always just use objects and just cast it to what we want, right?

Comment: @OndrejTokar Yes, but you would have to cast, and the compiler can not see if that cast is correct at compile time.

Comment: Hmm I see (almost). Thank you

Comment: @JornVernee would you mind telling me why doesn't T get erased e.g. in collection? Or if it does, how is it handled?

Comment: @OndrejTokar It does get erased, all generics do, it was done to be backward compatible with VMs that were made before the addition of generics. You could also check out [Why Use Generics?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), it shows some "before and after" code. The compiler will insert casts back from `Object` to the required type (after some thorough type checking, which could be hard to do by hand).

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot!